# Problem with dependencies in ResourceConfig on Jersey

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have a `Jersey` / `Spring` project (`Project A` : `com.project.a`) on `Eclipse` that depends on another (`Project B` : `com.project.b`).

`Eclipse` does not show any error on the projects until building and running the application on a local `Tomcat` server.

It throws this error:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
MultiException stack 1 of 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/project/b/SomeClassToRegister
    at com.project.a.CustomApplication.<init>(CustomApplication.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1009)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:905)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:997)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:989)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:340)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5449)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5747)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.b.SomeClassToRegister
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1955)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1798)
    ... 28 more

Jul 09, 2019 5:52:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [com.project.a.CustomApplication] in web application [/someApplication] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.b.SomeClassToRegister
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1955)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1798)
    at com.project.a.CustomApplication.<init>(CustomApplication.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1009)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:905)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:997)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:989)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:340)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5449)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5747)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`CustomApplication` extends `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig` and is trying to register that class as follows:

```
public class CustomApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public CustomApplication() {
        // Specify packages of java code.
        packages("com.project.a");
        packages("com.project.b"); //>>> Line 30
        register(com.project.b.SomeClassToRegister.class); //>>> Line 31
    }

}
```

Interestingly, `Line 30` calls the main package of com.project.b with no problem, but the code crashes on `line 31`. `com.project.b.SomeClassToRegister` exists on the dependency `com.project.b` .

After the error is shown, the `welcome-file` `jsp` page for the server is shown normally, but every endpoint throws the same `NoClassDefFoundError` error when accessed.

The build path of `Project A` has `Project B` as a listed dependency and `Project B` is also listed as part of the `Web Deployment Assembly` packaging of `Project A`.

I am currently running it on a local Tomcat server with the following resource configuration. I have tried to remove the duplicate appearance of Project B with the same result.

[image]

Am I missing anything about linking the two projects together that might be the cause of the error?

Comment: maybe latest/correct version of project b wasn't deploy to tomcat

Comment: @user7294900 thank you for your comment. I have added the resource configuration I am using to run the server to my question. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling a lot with the configurations of both projects, what worked for me was :

- Go to Properties of Project A
- Java Build Path
- Source
- Add folder src/main/java of Project B
- Apply and close
- Clean projects and run